# Jenkins declarative pipeline add groovy postbuild script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have groovy postbuild script

```
def error = manager.getLogMatcher(".*(Error:(.*)))
if(error?.matches()) {
    manager. addShortText(matcher.group(1))
}
```

Now I'm trying to convert this into declarative pipeline syntax

```
pipeline{
    post{
       failure{}
    }
}
```

So In failure tab can I add groovy script? or I have to add stage? I see there is jenkins-badge-plugin but not sure how to add regex to find text and then add batch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add script block inside failure as follows and there you can put your post build groovy script:

```
pipeline{
    post{
       failure{
           script{
             //Add your post build script code in case of failure
           }
       }
    }
}
```